# how to set default file name extension in CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::EnableFileBrowseButton?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how to give default file name extension in CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::EnableFileBrowseButton? How the arguments should be passed? I tried like following code.

```
CMFCEditBrowseCtrl py_file_path;
py_file_path.EnableFileBrowseButton(_T"PY",_T"*.py");
```

But it is not displaying the .py files. It says "no items matches". I guess there is some problem with the `lpszDefExt` and `lpszFilter` values i use. Could anyone tell me what is the value of those arguments to list all .py files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set it like this:

```
CMFCEditBrowseCtrl py_file_path;
py_file_path.EnableFileBrowseButton(_T("PY"), _T("Python files|*.py||"));
```

The final argument is a filter string, where the description and filter are delimited by `|`.

Comment: What is final "||" string in  "Python files|*.py||" means?

Comment: @Kumar That's the terminator - it indicates that there are no more filters in the string and is used in place of the null terminator. So you could have multiple filters like `"Python files|*.py|All files|*.*||"` for example.

Comment: Do you know how to set it so that the second filter index is selected by default? And, do you know how to set teh filter index to match the existing file name (if you are redisplaying the browse window)?