# Setting the supported file types for a MFCBrowseEdit control in File mode?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have a **MFC Browse Edit** control on my dialog:

[image: Sample Dialog]

When I hit the **Browse** button I see a **File** dialog, but it has no concept of **file types**:

[image: File Types]

The list of file types is empty. Now, I know I can type something like ***.jpg** to filter for JPG images but ideally I want this filetypes list to include a basic set of image file types and a generic one to show all the image file types.

I have set the browse mode to **File** but I can't see any other settings to customize the file dialog behaviour:

[image: Resource Editor Properties]

This is the snippet from RC file:

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_BROWSE_SPECIAL_EVENT_VIDEOCONF_PATH_IMAGE,
                "MfcEditBrowse",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x80,14,32,288,14
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you using the `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` class (your question title is a wee bit confusing)?

Comment: Correct. Feel free to re-word my question title.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950588/how-to-set-default-file-name-extension-in-cmfceditbrowsectrlenablefilebrowsebu Think it might be answer.